# Running new project from WebStorm interface crashes while running from shell doesn't?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, webstorm

In a new create-react-app generated project with `npx init create-react-app frontend --template typescript`. whenever I try to run the `start` npm script the following error pops up:

```
> frontend@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

./frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:348
    } catch {
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (./frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:28:26)
```

However if I run it directly in a shell (either the terminal from WebStorm or a manually opened one) it runs perfectly fine, indicating the problem is with WebStorm configuration?

Closer inspection shows WebStorm runs:

```
/home/paul/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node /home/paul/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js run start --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto
```

Running that manually in a terminal also works perfectly fine. I've checked the selected Node and TypeScript versions in the project settings - those are all set correctly (node set to the `nvm` mainted 16.3.2 and npm to the corresponding versions, TypeScript based on the one in local node modules).

What is the cause of this running error (on a blank project)? And what is a solution?

Screenshots by request:

[image: Running]

Node settings:

[image: node settings]

---

Upon deeper inspection I notice that if I downgrade `react-scripts` from `5.0.0` to `3.4.4`. As well as `typescript` from `4.5.5` to `3.9.10` it works fine - however this is not really a sustainable situation.
Deeper inspection shows that problem does occur with react-scripts version 4.x

Comment: The error message suggests that you running an old version of Node.js that doesn't support [optional catch binding](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-catch-binding). But Node 16 does definitely support it. Do you run npm script from the editor or in the built-in terminal? Please share a screenshot of **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js** page and the full console content, including the command being run

Comment: @lena Just added the screenshots...

Comment: weird. Does the issue persist if you start the IDE from terminal?

Comment: @lena actually - no that seems to work. however "remove from favourites" "add back to favourites" doesn't fix it, running through the launch bar of ubuntu gives that bug. Yet running through `/opt/WebStorm/bin/webstorm.sh` doesn't give the issue. Problem is then that this isn't really the most userfriendly solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be a problem with your `$PATH` as the IDE sees it - you must have some old Node.js version that doesn't support [optional catch binding](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-catch-binding) in it.

When being launched from desktop/launch bar, WebStorm only sees environment variables configured in login shell, but not in interactive shell configuration files (like `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`), so the environment (including `$PATH`) is different from the one you have in terminal. Possible solutions:

- Workaround 1: make required variables available in a login shell by moving/copying them to the corresponding shell profile config
- Workaround 2: run IDE from a terminal to make it inherit terminal environment
- Workaround 3: edit IDE launcher and set command to `/bin/bash -l -i -c  "/opt/WebStorm/bin/webstorm.sh"`

Comment: Oh this seems indeed to be the problem, I removed the system wide node version (in favour to just keep nvm ones) and the error is now:
`/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`
Event though it still says it uses the nvm handled version to run the code.

Comment: While it's indeed "workaround" the problem is now isolated to ubuntu/gnome and I should look there to solve it. - I'm still a bit baffled that webstorm uses somewhere "hidden" the $PATH based node version that is different from the one in your project settings.

Comment: @paul23 *"I'm still a bit baffled that webstorm uses somewhere "hidden" the $PATH based node version"* It's not WebStorm. This must be some tool that gets called somewhere in the chain. I would suggest you to monitor what processes gets launched when you run your project to see which one calls that `node`...